# c#.net can two DLL's mutually reference each other

Tags: c#, .net, dll, visual-studio-2019

I have a project solution in Visual Studio 2019.

There is a control project with the main GUI etc, I will label A.

A references Data-Layer (B) and Web-Service (C)

B references (C) very lightly

and C references (B) very heavily.

But, in general, can two DLL's mutually reference each other in the C#.net using Visual Studio context?

*Spoiler Alert:*  I think the answer is yes.  The situation described above seems to build and even-run correctly.  I imagine, it isn't a good practice, so I am creating a B2 in which C references B2, B2 does NOT reference C, and A references B,B2, and C as needed.  B will reference C but not be referenced by it.

Comment: Best design is probably something like an interface layer/assembly.   Either something to abstract away the light part of "C" that "B" references or vice versa.  Make them both refer to it.  One implement it, the other consume it.  This is a good case for DI

Comment: @Joe please feel free to expand your comment to an answer, if you want to -- JosephDoggie

Comment: #@Joe I eventually removed the mutual dependency, along the lines you suggested.

Comment: It appears the compiler allows mutually referencing DLL's, however, if there is a CIRCULAR reference situation, it will NOT allow it.